# JQuery mobile / phonegap textarea doesn't work with clipboard paste

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I wrote a jquery mobile / phonegap app where I need to paste some text into a textarea. The standard functionality is that a taphold displays a paste icon, which pastes the clipboard text into the textarea. This paste icon doesn't show up. It shows up in other apps.

```
<textarea id="fillin_textarea" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" name="textarea" rows="8" cols="40" style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
```

Is there an attribute in jQuery mobile I can set?

Or maybe a manifest problem?

Thanks for help ...

Comment: I would guess, because you are mentioning manifest that you are talking about Android platform?

Comment: are u using custom css in ur mobile app?

Comment: @Gajotres: Yes, its Android.

Comment: @hungerpain: I am not using custom css, just css from theme roller.